# Disabling checkboxes after checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes, each one of them relating to a row in a table. Each row belongs to a client. I have used the client name as the class of the checkboxes. I need only checkboxes that share the same class to be enabled once the first checkbox has been ticked.

```
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-9" name="bill[]" id="bill[]" onchange="check();">
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-10" name="bill[]" id="bill[]" onchange="check();">
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-11" name="bill[]" id="bill[]" onchange="check();">
<input class="John Doe" type="checkbox" value="Domain-12" name="bill[]" id="bill[]" onchange="check();">
```

```js
function check(){
    $("#bill").on("change", function() {
        if ($('#bill').attr('class') !== $(this).attr("class")) {
            $(".bill").attr("class").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#bill").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `.prop` over `.attr`

Comment: Why `inline-events` as well as `jQ` event binding ?

Comment: @RayonDabre tried that , still doesnt work

Comment: Maybe `if ($('bill').attr('class') !== $(this).className()) {` is missing a dot inside jquery specifier?

Comment: `$("#bill").on("change", function()`    is incorrect, as # is an id selector and there's no element with `id = bill`.  

`if ($('bill').attr('class') !== $(this).className()) {`     missing dot in selector

`$(".bill").attr("disabled", "disabled");`   I think, this will disable all elements

Comment: You don't have an element with id `#bill`. There is also no tag named `bill` and there aren't any elements with class `.bill` . So first thing to do is make the selectors work I guess

Comment: Pay attention to you are trying. Disable the checkbox will produce that **this checkbox never will be submitted**. To avoid this, try `readonly`  instead of  `disabled`

Comment: @ndev pls try my code it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```js
 $('input[name*=bill]').change(function() {
   $t = $(this);
   var $th = $(this).attr('class');
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('input[name*=bill]').each(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('class') != $th) {
         $(this).not($t).prop('disabled', true);
       }
     });
   } else {
     $('input[name*=bill]').each(function() {
       if ($(this).attr('class') != $th) {
         $(this).not($t).prop('disabled', false);
       }
     });
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-9" name="bill[]">
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-10" name="bill[]">
<input class="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-11" name="bill[]">
<input class="John Doe" type="checkbox" value="Domain-12" name="bill[]">
```

Comment: when ticking the first box it disables boxes 2/3 and enables 4, it should disable 4 and keep 2/3 enabled. once box 4 is ticked all boxes should be disabled but it waits until another box is ticked before disabling the others

Comment: got it now, i changed onchange to onclick, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

`disabled` is a `property` not an `attribute`. so use `prop` instead of `attr`.

```
<script>
function check(){
$("[name='bill']").on("change", function() {
if ($("[name='bill']").attr('class') !== $(this).className()) {
$("[name='bill']").prop('disabled', true); 
} else {
$("[name='bill']").prop('disabled', false); 
}
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: How, if there aren't elements with class 'bill', or id 'bill', or tag 'bill'?

Comment: @Pimskie even if I add id = bill it still doesnt work, i tried that before posting this question !

Comment: @ndev, now check.. i replace `"bill"` with `[name='bill']`

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try my code:
i have made some change in your code and it will help you out:

```
<input class="bill" client="Alexander David" value="Domain-9" name="bill[]" type="checkbox">
<input client="Alexander David" value="Domain-10" name="bill[]" class="bill" type="checkbox">
<input client="Alexander David" value="Domain-11" name="bill[]" class="bill" type="checkbox">
<input client="John Doe" value="Domain-12" name="bill[]" class="bill" type="checkbox">
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bill').change(function(){
      var client = $(this).attr('client');
      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
        $('input[client='+client+']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
      }
      else
       $('input[client='+client+']').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
<script>
```

Comment: have you changed the html also

Comment: i have put the jquery code inside the ready function do that and check again

Answer (score 0):

Using classNames might be problematic (because of the spaces). Consider using a `data` attribute instead.

In this example we toggle the `disabled` property of all matched inputs:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function(){
      var $this = $(this),
          thisIdent = $this.data("ident");

      $("[data-ident='"+thisIdent+"']").not($this).prop("disabled",$this.is(":checked"));

  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-ident="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-9"    name="bill[]">
<input data-ident="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-10" name="bill[]">
<input data-ident="Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-11" name="bill[]">
<input data-ident="John Doe" type="checkbox" value="Domain-12" name="bill[]">
```

Comment: when ticking the first box it disables boxes 2/3 and enables 4, it should disable 4 and keep 2/3 enabled. once box 4 is ticked all boxes should be disabled but it waits until another box is ticked before disabling the others

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the `onChange` function with `#bill` which means `bill` is an ID. But in your HTML it is the name of the elements and there is no ID in the check boxes. So your code is not working.

Again when an element is disabled click/change/check - no event will work on it. So you have to think about some alternative like putting a class on the checkbox to make it feel like disabled.

```
<input class="billCheck Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-9"    name="bill[]">
<input class="billCheck Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-10" name="bill[]">
<input class="billCheck Alexander David" type="checkbox" value="Domain-11" name="bill[]">
<input class="billCheck John Doe" type="checkbox" value="Domain-12" name="bill[]">


<script type="text/javascript" >
        $(".billCheck").on("click", function() {
              if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $(this).addClass("disabled");
              } else {
                $(this).removeClass("disabled");
              }
         });

        $('input.disabled').on('click', function(evt) {
               evt.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        input.disabled {
           opacity : .50;
           filter  : alpha(opacity=50); /* IE<9 */
           cursor  : default;
        }
    </style>
```

I think this matches with what you want.